# how do you pass multiple packed propstogether

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

when i try the below i get this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: navbar.makeButtonClick is not a function

Source
.next/static/chunks/pages/index.js (19:29) @ onClick

  17 | return(
  18 |   <button href='#' className = {`${styleNavbar.menu__link} ${styleNavbar.r_link} ${styleNavbar.text_underlined}`}{...props}
> 19 |     onClick={()=>{navbar.makeButtonClick(!navbar.buttonClick);
     |                           ^
  20 |                   userprops.makeRefresh(!userprops.refresh);
  21 |                   }}>
  22 |     {navprops.navbutton}
```

but i really dont get it..`makeButtonClick` is an option, i've used the same method to pass `mainprops` and `userprops` and it worked...

**whole component:**

```
import styleNavbar from '../../../styles/Main/Navbar.module.css'
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';


const NavButtonCreator = (props) => {
  const {mainprops,userprops,navbar,navprops,...styleprops} = props;

  return(
    <button href='#' className = {`${styleNavbar.menu__link} ${styleNavbar.r_link} ${styleNavbar.text_underlined}`}{...props}
      onClick={()=>{navbar.makeButtonClick(!navbar.buttonClick);
                    userprops.makeRefresh(!userprops.refresh);
                    }}>
      {navprops.navbutton}
    </button>
  );
};

const NavButtonStyler = (props) => {
  const {mainprops,userprops,navbar,...navprops} = props;

  return(
    <>
    {props.place=='left'&&
      <div className=''>
        <NavButtonCreator mainprops={mainprops} userprops={userprops} navbar={navbar} navprops={navprops} />
      </div>}

    {props.place=='center'&&
      <div className='absolute left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 '>
        <NavButtonCreator mainprops={mainprops} userprops={userprops} navbar={navbar} navprops={navprops} />
      </div>}

    {props.place=='right'&&
      <div className='absolute right-0'>
        <NavButtonCreator mainprops={mainprops} userprops={userprops} navbar={navbar} navprops={navprops} />
      </div>}

    </>  
  )
};

const Navbar = (props) => {
  const {mainprops, ...userprops} = props;
  const [buttonClick, makeButtonClick] = useState(false);

  const navbar = {
    buttonClick,
    makeButtonClick
};


  useEffect(()=>{ 
    return(
      ()=>{ userprops.setPageId(navbutton);
          }
    );
  },[buttonClick]);


  if (userprops.visitorType == 'viewer') {
    return(
      <div>
        <nav className = {`${styleNavbar.page__menu} ${styleNavbar.page__custom_settings} ${styleNavbar.menu}`} >
          <ul className = {`${styleNavbar.menu__list} ${styleNavbar.r_list}`} >
              <NavButtonStyler mainprops={mainprops} userprops={userprops} {...navbar} place='left'   navbutton='the world'         />
              <NavButtonStyler mainprops={mainprops} userprops={userprops} {...navbar} place='left'   navbutton='the country'          />
              <NavButtonStyler mainprops={mainprops} userprops={userprops} {...navbar} place='left'   navbutton='the state'         />
              <NavButtonStyler mainprops={mainprops} userprops={userprops} {...navbar} place='center' navbutton='the city'   />
              <NavButtonStyler mainprops={mainprops} userprops={userprops} {...navbar} place='right'  navbutton='the town'  />
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    )}
  };

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Navbar` component, you are unpacking the `navbar` object when passing it to `NavButtonStyler` like this: `{...navbar}`.

Unpacking the object, means that the properties of the object (`buttonClick` and `makeButtonClick` in this case), are passed among the normal props to the component.

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Keep the unpacking, and make `NavButtonStyler` accept `buttonClick` and `makeButtonClick`. You would then need to repack them for passing to `NavButtonCreator`, or make `NavButtonCreator` accept them as separate props. Repacking can be done like this:

```
const NavButtonCreator = (props) => {
    const {mainprops,userprops,buttonClick,makeButtonClick,navprops,...styleprops} = props;
    const navbar = { buttonClick, makeButtonClick };
```

2. Or pass `navbar` as a normal property in `Navbar`:

```
<NavButtonStyler mainprops={mainprops} userprops={userprops} navbar={navbar} place='left'   navbutton='the world'         />
```

Comment: three guys, one answer :D

Comment: @jebbie thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

In each of the `NavButtonStyler` components (inside the `Navbar`), you're unpacking the `navbar` prop:

```
<NavButtonStyler mainprops={mainprops} userprops={userprops} {...navbar} place='left'   navbutton='the world'         />
                                                             ^ Here
```

This means that the `buttonClick` and `makeButtonClick` functions are passed as props. Just pass the `navbar` prop directly.

```
<NavButtonStyler mainprops={mainprops} userprops={userprops} navbar={navbar} place='left'   navbutton='the world'         />
```

Comment: yes this works too and it's cleaner to read ^^

Answer (score 1):

I got it, you are spreading `navbar` to your component `NavButtonStyler`.. By spreading the object "navbar", it will only transport the fields inside...

So the props which are arriving at `NavButtonStyler` is not `navbar` but `buttonClick` and `makeButtonClick` ;-)

So change that where you destructure your props in NavButtonStyler to:

```js
const {mainprops,userprops,buttonClick,makeButtonClick,...navprops} = props;
```

and remove `navbar.` in your click handler and it will work :)

Oh, and please, install and use https://prettier.io/ to get auto-formatted code and... don't call your state-setters "make"... they should follow a pattern like

```js
const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You destructures navbar while passing through component, so you need to use function directly instead of navbar.functionName

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer in more detail.